# colour a binary matrix matplotlib

Tags: python, matrix, matplotlib, wxpython

```
highlightc = np.zeros([N, N])
print highlightc
c = len(highlightc)
colour = [0.21]*c
colour = np.array(colour)
print colour
for x, y in hl:
    highlightc[x, y] = 1##set so binary matrix knows where to plot
h=ax.imshow((highlightc*colour), interpolation='nearest',cmap=plt.cm.spectral_r)
fig.canvas.draw()
```

I have created a binary matrix like so, and what I want to do is have the plots made a certain colour by multiplying a binary matrix with a number below zero. However my code above does not do this and the plots still remain black. I'm pretty sure its something to do with my colour array but I do not know how to edit it so, it is correct.
`highlightc` is a list which contains `[(1,109),(1,102),(67,102),etc]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ax.imshow(X)` adjusts the color scale so that the lowest value in X is mapped to the lowest color, and the highest value in X is mapped to the highest color in the `cmap`.

When you multiply `highlight` by a constant `colour`, the highest value in `X` drops from 1 to 0.21, but that has no effect on `ax.imshow` since the color scale gets adjusted as well, thwarting your intention.

If, however, you supply `vmin=0`, `vmax=1` parameters, then `ax.imshow` will not adjust the color range -- it will associate 0 with the lowest color and 1 with the highest:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

N = 150
highlightc = np.zeros([N, N])

M = 1000
hl = np.random.randint(N, size=(M, 2))
highlightc[zip(*hl)] = 1

colour = 0.21
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
h = ax.imshow(
    (highlightc * colour), interpolation='nearest', cmap=plt.cm.spectral_r,
    vmin=0, vmax=1)
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: You can adjust the color limits after-the-fact with `h.set_clim([vmin, vmax])`